# Mamba env throws "AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'func'"

Tags: mamba

I'm suddenly getting the following error when running `mamba env export`:

```bash
$ mamba env export
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/scicore/home/neher/roemer0001/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda/exception_handler.py", line 17, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/scicore/home/neher/roemer0001/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mamba/mamba.py", line 926, in exception_converter
        raise e
      File "/scicore/home/neher/roemer0001/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mamba/mamba.py", line 919, in exception_converter
        exit_code = _wrapped_main(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/scicore/home/neher/roemer0001/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mamba/mamba.py", line 877, in _wrapped_main
        result = do_call(parsed_args, p)
      File "/scicore/home/neher/roemer0001/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mamba/mamba.py", line 709, in do_call
        relative_mod, func_name = args.func.rsplit(".", 1)
    AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'func'
```

Some system details:

```
mamba 1.4.9
conda 23.7.2
python 3.9.16.final.0
__archspec=1=x86_64
__glibc=2.17=0
__linux=3.10.0=0
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a known bug of `mamba <=1.4.9` when used with `conda>=23.7.0` (issues [[1]](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge/issues/475) [[2]](https://github.com/mamba-org/mamba/issues/2715)).

It should be fixed by at least one of:

- upgrading `mamba` to `>=1.5.0`
- downgrading `conda` to `<23.7.0`: `mamba install conda==23.5.2`
- use `conda` or `micromamba` instead of `mamba` for the commands that fail

Comment: Confirming, when I download to `conda=23.5.2` the issue stated by PO is resolved, but now I get `Could not load conda plugin `conda-build`: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable` for any command in any non-base env, but base env is fine.

Comment: @MarkMikofski This might be a different issue, can you open an issue here with full stack trace and debugging output please? https://github.com/mamba-org/mamba/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=bug.yml

Comment: I don't think it's a mamba issue, here's the stack trace: `conda env list -vvv` Could not load conda plugin `conda-build`: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
WARNING conda.plugins.manager:load_entrypoints(85): Could not load conda plugin `conda-build`: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable -- only started after mamba-1.4.9 and downgrade to conda-23.5.2

Comment: @MarkMikofski I'm not quite sure what `conda env list` has to do with this question, as this question is about `mamba` not `conda`.